# Wireless mouse shuts off after several second

Tags: mouse

My Logitech wireless mouse just started constantly shutting off after about 7 or 8 seconds, using Ubuntu 16.04. In a couple of other of posts about somewhat similar problem, related to a bluetooth mouse, some suggested that the laptop was shutting down the mouse for power saving, but I couldn't find any solution that seemed related to my issue.

Comment: Maybe you need to replace the battery?

Comment: i've tested it with 2 different brand new batteries, same result